# Continuous-time Kalman filter with no observation/measurement noise

Tags: stochastic-processes, kalman-filter, stochastic-calculus

The continuous-time (linear) state space model can be written

\begin{align*}  
   \text{d}\mathbf{x}_t &= \mathbf{F} \,\mathbf{x}_t \, \text{d}t +
   \mathbf{G} \,\text{d} \boldsymbol{\beta}_t \\
   \text{d} \mathbf{z}_t &= \mathbf{H} \,\mathbf{x}_t \, \text{d}t +
   \text{d}\boldsymbol{\eta}_t  
\end{align*}

where $\mathbf{x}_t$ is the unobserved state and $\mathbf{z}_t$ is the
observed process, while $\boldsymbol{\beta}_t$ and
$\boldsymbol{\eta}_t$ are independent Brownian motions. A special case
is when the term $\text{d} \boldsymbol{\eta}_t$ is discarded from the
second equation (the observation equation). This concerns for instance
Continuous-Time Auto-Regressive models. However, most books seem to
consider only the case with measurement noise: see for instance
[Jazwinski](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486462749.html),
[Øskendal](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540047582) or [Sarkka
and
Solin](https://www.cambridge.org/fi/academic/subjects/statistics-probability/applied-probability-and-stochastic-networks/applied-stochastic-differential-equations?format=PB).

Where can we find a description/discussion of the KF for the case with no
measurement noise?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the math still works if you simply set the covariance matrix of $\eta$ to zero?

Comment: Yes the results could be obtained when this covariance, say $\mathbf{R}$, tends to zero. Yet It is not obvious since $\mathbf{R}^{-1}$ is used in the equations. See eqs (10.38) in Sarkka and Solin (freely available online).

Comment: Is it? In the recursion equations in Durbin & Koopman it is not. I imagine that there will be some considerations around initialisation.

Comment: In Durbin & Koopman (sec 3.10 in my version) It seems that only discrete-time observations are considered, which makes a huge difference with the (ideal) continously oberved case. This corresponds to the limit of discrete-time obs. when the maximal step $t_{i+1} - t_i$ tends to zero.

Comment: Sure. I hadn't considered that. Nevertheless the intuition driving me here is that  GPs without 'observation noise' are still GPs.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure that differential equations still hold for the expectation and the covariance of the Gaussian distribution $\mathbf{x}_t \vert \mathcal{Z}_t$, and I hope to find them somewhere.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I've been wondering if the computation can be speeded-up if we assume away observation noise.

Comment: Well I think I have a part of the answer: under general conditions on the SS model, when there is no measurement noise,  the state vector $\mathbf{x}_t$ lies in the $\sigma$-field generated by the obsevations available at time $t$, i.e. by $\{y_s: \, s \leq t \}$. So the filtering covariance matrix is zero.